What is an applied argument?
What does an applied argument mean?
I have an assignment and cannot seem to understand this. Can we say that a sentence doesn’t have an applied argument when it doesn’t have a direct object?

I think you'll need to give us some indication of what grammatical theory or framework you're working in. I know I'm not up to date with grammatical theory, but I've never heard of an "applied argument".

It sounds like "applied object" may just refer to an oblique object that is promoted to direct object by an applicative construction. But a quotation / the context where you found the term may enable a more specific and helpful answer.
